# mysql result with order by is different from order by and limit

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have a table A with columns id, age.

Two queries below return different result and I don't know why:

```
SELECT distinct a.id id FROM A a ORDER BY a.age DESC
SELECT distinct a.id id FROM A a ORDER BY a.age DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Any ideas? I would expect the second query to return the first 10 results of the first query.

**EDIT:**

What I forgot to say is that there are rows with the same age. So I think it has something to do with it.

Comment: It's a copy paste typo, I meant OFFSET 0 (anyway it doesn't work properly for OFFSET 10 as well)

Comment: I'm sceptical. Can you demonstrate this?

Comment: How can I demonstrate it?

Comment: By providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle?

Comment: What does your first query returns and what does the second one?

Comment: That edit was quite an important point.

Comment: yes you're right, sorry...

Comment: So do you have a solution/explanation for the problem??

Comment: Do you have a sqlfiddle for same?

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised they work.  In most databases you would get a syntax error, because `a.age` is not in the `select`.  I know that MySQL extends the `GROUP BY` to allow the use of un-aggregated columns.  I presume it has the same reasoning for `SELECT DISTINCT`.  That is, age comes from an indeterminate row for each `id`.  It is so indeterminate that it might change from one query to another.

Here are two appropriate ways to write the query:

```
SELECT distinct a.id, a.age
FROM A a
ORDER BY a.age DESC;
```

or:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM A a
ORDER BY MIN(a.age) DESC;   -- Or perhaps MAX(a.age) or AVG(a.age)
```

These should have more stable results, with or without the `LIMIT`.

Comment: Are we seeing the same question?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I'm not sure why it's happening. I'm using mysql and maybe the implementation of the query when adding limit is different from when without it.
Any way, I added in the ORDER BY a.id. This kept the order when adding limit.

So this is how the query looks:

```
SELECT distinct a.id id FROM A a ORDER BY a.age DESC, a.id LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: id is indexed, right? While it's obviously good practice to order by the columns in the select, I'm surprised that this actually has any impact on the result set.